# How can I plot log in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function like this which is called entropy 
`H(y)=(summation over y)-p(y)*log2(p(y)`.

I want to plot it for the value between 0 and 1 and has the maximum value in p(y)=0.5 which is equal to 1.
I am not able to plot this with plt.plot, how could I achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h_y=[]
p_y=np.array([0,0.5,1])
for i in range(0,2):
   a=np.sum(-np.nan_to_num(p_y[i]*np.log2(p_y[i])))
   h_y=a.append(a)
plt.plot(h_y)
```

the result will be logarithmic which has the maximum value in p_y=0.5 and 0 in p_y=0,1

Comment: Please input the correct indentations and fix the code (e.g. `h_y=a.append(a)` gives an error), or else explain your error. Otherwise people cannot reproduce your code. `plt.semilogx, plt.semilogy, plt.loglog` will create logaritmic scales on one or both axis.

Comment: You're trying to append to a numpy array as if it were a list. You're passing in a zero to `np.log2()`, and where it's not allowed. Check out the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.htm) on plotting on log and semilog axes, but fix the other problems first.

Comment: @hyperTrashPanda I solved the nan value by using     'np.nan_no_num'

Comment: Nice. I provided a complete example code as an answer below, let me know if it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't give me the good result, please take a look at this diagram at this page, maybe will be more instructive than what I explained, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my example of your code and function being plotted, in both normal and semilog plots.

`numpy` is great for vectorized operations, you avoid for-loops and write very readable code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h_y=[]
x = np.arange(0.001, 1, 0.001)
y = -x*np.log2(x) - (1-x)*np.log2(1-x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('foo.png')

plt.semilogx(x,y)
plt.savefig('bar.png')

plt.semilogy(x,y)
plt.savefig('baz.png')
```

Let me know if I can help with anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it didn't give me what I wanted, please take a look at this diagram maybe will be more instructive than what I explained [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function)

Comment: Thanks for the link, you had provided a wrong function in the beginning. Try to run the code again, with the correct Binary Entropy definition.

Comment: I did with this code that you mentioned but look at the axis for horizontal axis it should be between [0 1] and vertical axis also between [0 1] however your code gives the value between 10^-2 until 10^0

Comment: I think, I found out what should I do, instead of 'plt.semilogy' I should use this code plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show(), it worked now, thanks again

Comment: Yes, `semilog{x,y}`, is for specific use-cases that might not fit your current needs, that's why I added all three type of plots.. Feel free to accept an answer so the question can close successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide `plt.plot` with two arguments ([doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.2/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py)): first - list of parameters, second - list of entropy values for given parameters. Use `plt.show()` to actualy display you plot.

Also logarithm is undefined for 0, so replace that value with something else close to 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def entropy(y):
    return - y * math.log2(y)

p_y=[0.01,0.5,1]
plt.plot(p_y, [entropy(y) for y in p_y])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(0., 1, 0.001)
y = -x*np.log2(x) - (1-x)*np.log2(1-x)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

finally it worked with this algorithm, Thanks